# Scraping Multiple Tables from webpage Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape multiple tables from the webpage below. But, my code is getting only the first table, even though all the tables are nested in the same tr and td tags. 
That's my attempt:

```
 url = "http://zipnet.in/index.php?page=missing_person_search&criteria=browse_all&Page_No=1"
 r = requests.get(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
 tables = soup.find('table', border=1)
 for row in tables.findAll('tr'):
 sleep (3)
 col = row.findAll('td')
 fields = col[0].string
 details = col[1].string
 record = (fields, details)
 print (record)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `tables = soup.findAll("table")` or use pandas if you have installed it  `pandas.readhtml(str(soup))`

Comment: @AlbinPaul, I got this error, when I did soup.findAll, AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: your current proble can be that you have two findAll` - so finally you have something like `soup.findAll('table',border=1).findAll('tr')`. After you use first `findAll` you have to use `for` loop (`for item in tables:`) and use second `findAll` with every table separatelly - `item.findAll()`.

Comment: maybe you should search all tables inside first table using `soup.find('table', border=1).findAll('table')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a go and get all the tables available in that page especially the ones containing required records:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://zipnet.in/index.php?page=missing_person_search&criteria=browse_all&Page_No=1"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
for trow in soup.select("table#AutoNumber15"):
    data = [[' '.join(item.text.split()) for item in tcel.select("td")]
            for tcel in trow.select("tr")]
    print(data)
```

Comment: Btw, you can always kick out any unwanted portion you do not want to keep, as in if you keep only the first few records of each profile then you can bring about a minor change like `tcel in trow.select("tr")[0:8]]`. That's it.

Comment: Thanks much, Shahin.